# Why does Git Extensions show two entries in the log for a single stash?

Tags: git, git-extensions

When I create a stash, the contents of the stash show up in [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) like a commit with two parents, one of which is the actual commit it stems from, and the other is an index which is named for that commit, but with no content. What's going on here?

[image: Git Extensions log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how git differentiates between items that were in the index (things that you git add'ed before git stash) and items that were in the working tree only.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simpler answer than I thought. I guess I've just never seen anything in the index because I only use it right before I commit.